# OpenGl antialiasing in lwjgl (Minecraft)

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl, antialiasing

Is it possible to have an antialiasing shader (if so how) , or is it only possible with fbos based on information below.

.

I am trying to add anti aliasing to the gui in Minecraft which runs off lwjgl.

I first came upon this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdn13TRWEM0

In which he talks about how to make antialiasing in lwjgl, But since minecraft uses another framebuffer,

```
            Display.create((new PixelFormat()).withDepthBits(24).withSamples(8));
            GL11.glEnable(GL13.GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

Dosen't work

From there in another video he describes doing it with fbos
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCBoIvVmYgk

Would this be the only way for me to implement anti aliasing, or is it possible an easier way.

Optifine allows for antialiasing, but it only happens within minecraft games[image]

With no antialiasing a circle looks like this[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which game version and modding framework are you using? There are a few ways of doing this, I happen to know one for fabricmc on everything up from 1.17.

(disclaimer: this library is made and maintained by me)

https://github.com/0x3C50/Renderer is a rendering library for modern fabric, that includes a MSAAFramebuffer you can use to render things anti aliased. Just wrap your rendering code in

```java
MSAAFramebuffer.use(samples, () -> {
    // render
});
```

Comment: I'm using mcp. So vanilla minecraft, no frameworks.